Spring Boot update: Full authentication is required to access this resource
I have a web application which is migrated from spring boot 2.3.4 to 2.7.18. All the other dependencies have been updated accordingly. After migrating the below is the issue once we try to access any API, before it was working fine.
Error:
[org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource]
I even have the below SecurityConfiguration class which is updated as per the spring security 5.7.x(compatible with spring boot 2.7.18)
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport;

@Configuration
@Import({ SecurityProblemSupport.class })
//@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
      .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
          .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")).permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()) //other URLs are only allowed authenticated users.
      .httpBasic();
  return http.build();
  }
}

The below is pom.xml:
  
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.7.18
         
    
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        **/config/**,
        **/aop/**,
        **/dto/**.java,
        **/dao/**.java,
        **/errors/*Trait.java,
        **/web/rest/constants/**,
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
    <pi.version>3.59.6</pi.version>
    <mongodb.version>5.1.3</mongodb.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
                <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
                <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
        <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
        <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
        <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>0.22.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.12</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-archaius</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- added for powermock in pluginDaoImpl -->
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
                <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <version>${mongodb.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>
    </dependency>

    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
                <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
     <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.101.Final</version>
    </dependency>
        
</dependencies>

I have the below config as well in bootstrap.yml:
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"

Note: Even existing swagger also stopped working due to 401 error.
Could anyone throw a light on this what happens after spring boot migration.
